# Why is second author completely in small caps?

Tags: jurabib

According to the jurabib documentation, it should be possible to format first name and last name of author/editor in a different way. Why does this work for the first author, but not for the second?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[authorformat={reducedifibidem,allreversed},citefull=first]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\jbauthorfont}{\mdseries\scshape}
\renewcommand*{\jbauthorfnfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand*{\biblnfont}{\mdseries\scshape}
\renewcommand*{\bibfnfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand*{\bibelnfont}{\mdseries\scshape}
\renewcommand*{\bibefnfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand*{\jborgauthorfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand*{\jbannotatorfont}{\mdseries}

\begin{filecontents}{Lit.bib}
@Book{Editor,
  title      = {Scriptores rervm Germanicarvm, praecipve Saxonicarvm},
  year       = {1728},
  editor     = {Johann Burchard Mencke and Vorname Nachname},
  address    = {Leipzig}
}
@Book{Author,
  title      = {Scriptores rervm Germanicarvm, praecipve Saxonicarvm},
  year       = {1728},
  author     = {Johann Burchard Mencke and Vorname Nachname},
  address    = {Leipzig}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    Author\footcite{Author}
    Editor\footcite{Editor}
    \nobibliography{Lit}
    \bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should specify `\upshape` in `\jbauthorfnfont` (otherwise while the **series** is re-specified as `mdseries`, the **shape** remains unaltered at `scshape`-- being two ***independent*** features of a font)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[authorformat={reducedifibidem,allreversed},citefull=first]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\jbauthorfont}{\mdseries\scshape}
\renewcommand*{\jbauthorfnfont}{\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\biblnfont}{\mdseries\scshape}
\renewcommand*{\bibfnfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand*{\bibelnfont}{\mdseries\scshape}
\renewcommand*{\bibefnfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand*{\jborgauthorfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand*{\jbannotatorfont}{\mdseries}

\begin{filecontents}{Lit.bib}
@Book{Editor,
    title      = {Scriptores rervm Germanicarvm, praecipve Saxonicarvm},
    year       = {1728},
    editor     = {Johann Burchard Mencke and Vorname Nachname},
    address    = {Leipzig}
}
@Book{Author,
    title      = {Scriptores rervm Germanicarvm, praecipve Saxonicarvm},
    year       = {1728},
    author     = {Johann Burchard Mencke and Vorname Nachname},
    address    = {Leipzig}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
        Author\footcite{Author}
        Editor\footcite{Editor}
        \nobibliography{Lit}
        \bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\end{document}
```

to get things right:

[image]

Comment: Or perhaps `\normalfont` to reset everything.